# Node js image processing without filesystem?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I need to edit image in my react native app, i have installed jimp as the image processing module but [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) required `fs`.

As we know that react native dosen't have a node environment so it does not provide the nodejs `fs` module.

There is alternatives to `fs` in react native, such as [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs), but jimp don't know about `react-native-fs` it knows about `fs`.

I need to edit the image on the client side.

I can read an image data, for example in `base64`. As jimp need `fs` as a dependency so i cant manipulate using that data, any suggestion for this case? Is there any module that allows image processing in nodejs without requiring nodejs `fs` module?

Comment: Do you care whether the image processing happens on the client side or server side ?  If server side is OK then sure nodejs can access `fs` to perform image processing and then send the answer back to the client front end app

Comment: @ScottStensland Hi, I want to process the image on the client side

Comment: You can always use buffer/blob/stream as jimp itself reads file as buffer and then process it. Just a bit of tweak should help you out here

Comment: for example here : 
Jimp.read(lenna.buffer, function (err, image) {
    // do stuff with the image (if no exception)
});
Jimp reads from a buffer

Comment: @binariedMe Hi, that's what i was also thinking, but when i import jimp `import jimp from 'jimp'` it throws a `fs` not supported error on the device.

Comment: @rakibtg Well I followed this link and I had no issues with jimp. Can you try this out : https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/blob/master/browser/README.md ?

Comment: @akibtg did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to import the npm version of Jimp which requires "fs" library of node.js.

Instead if you import this cdn : 
[JIMP CDN](https://cdn.rawgit.com/oliver-moran/jimp/v0.2.27/browser/lib/jimp.min.js)

And then try with sample example this :

```
Jimp.read("lenna.png").then(function (lenna) {
lenna.resize(256, 256)            // resize
     .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
     .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
     .getBase64(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, function (err, src) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("src", src);
          document.body.appendChild(img);
     });
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

You should be able to use all the api features of Jimp.